# WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to setup a graph database, I have two csv files . I have successfully setup on of the csv's, the first one works fine.

First CSV :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/rraina/Desktop/acc.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (providerName:ProviderName { name: csvLine.providerName })
MERGE (container:Container { name: csvLine.CONTAINER })
MERGE (asset:Asset { name: csvLine.isAsset })
CREATE (account:Account { accountName: csvLine.accountName, id: csvLine.id})
CREATE (account)-[:ACCOUNTS_IN]->(providerName)
CREATE (account)-[:ACCOUNT_TYPE]->(container)
CREATE (account)-[:IS_ASSET]->(asset)
```

the CSV looks like this :

```
CONTAINER,accountName,accountStatus,accountNumber,isAsset,balance,id,lastUpdated,providerId,providerName,refreshinfo,isManual
reward,RAHUL RAINA,ACTIVE,xxxx0363,TRUE,3334,16294736,1433967380,9863,HSBC Bank Personal Banking,0|OK|1433967380|1433967380,FALSE
bank,SAVINGS ACCOUNT - RES,ACTIVE,xxxx5006,TRUE,6048.07,16294732,1433967401,9863,HSBC Bank Personal Banking,0|OK|1433967401|1433967401,FALSE
creditCard,VISA GOLD,ACTIVE,xxxx0363,FALSE,4885.56,16294492,1433967428,9863,HSBC Bank Personal Banking,0|OK|1433967428|1433967428,FALSE
bank,SBCHQ-GEN-PUB-IND-NONRURAL-INR,ACTIVE,xxxx6404,TRUE,24572.98,16294488,1433966054,9421,State Bank of India,0|OK|1433966054|1433966054,FALSE
```

I have been able to make the graph I require for this with the above query.

However when I am importing the 2nd csv and trying to add a relationship from trans.csv to acc.csv

trans.csv looks like this :

```
CONTAINER,id,amount,baseType,category,description,originalDescription,isManual,date,transactionDate,merchantName,status,accountId
bank,133817384,1400,DEBIT,ATM/Cash Withdrawals,ATM07JUN15 NFS 11:38:44A96103218ATM,ATM07JUN15 NFS 11:38:44A96103218ATM,FALSE,6/8/2015,6/8/2015,Cash Withdrawal,POSTED,16294732
bank,133815940,224,DEBIT,Transfers,TO TRANSFER INB Tinyowl Technology Privat,TO TRANSFER INB Tinyowl Technology Privat,FALSE,6/8/2015,6/8/2015,Transfer,POSTED,16294488
```

Query for importing the 2nd csv and making the relationship :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/rraina/Desktop/trans.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (baseType:BaseType { name: csvLine.baseType })
MERGE (category:Category { name: csvLine.category })
MERGE (merchantName:MerchantName { name: csvLine.merchantName })
MATCH (account:Account { id: csvLine.accountId }),(transaction:Transaction { id: csvLine.accountId })
CREATE (transaction:Transaction { description: csvLine.description, postedDate: csvLine.date,transactionDate: csvLine.transactionDate ,id: csvLine.id })
CREATE (transaction)-[:CATEGORY_IN]->(category)
CREATE (transaction)-[:TRANSACTED_AT]->(merchantName)
CREATE (transaction)-[:BASETYPE_OF]->(baseType)
```

I am getting this error :

```
WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH (line 5, column 1 (offset: 253))
"MATCH (account:Account { id: csvLine.accountId }),(transaction:Transaction { id: csvLine.accountId })"
```

I want all the transactions from transactions.csv to be related to accounts.csv if the acc.csv's : account.id `equals` trans.csv's : transaction.id

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just give it the `WITH` statement it is asking for?

Put the line:

```
WITH baseType, category, merchantName, csvLine
```

Between your last `MERGE` and your `MATCH`.

Comment: this resolves that error, but strangely it says now :  `csvLine not defined (line 7, column 30 (offset: 346))
"MATCH (account:Account { id: csvLine.accountId }),(transaction:Transaction { id: csvLine.accountId })"`

Comment: i was able to import csv from the first file

Comment: I missed the `csvLine` variable. I updated my answer by adding that to the `WITH` statement. Try it again with the new `WITH` statement.

Comment: yes, that did the job, but why does it say `transaction already declared (line 8, column 9 (offset: 407))
"CREATE (transaction:Transaction { description: row.description, postedDate: row.date,transactionDate: row.transactionDate ,id: row.id })"` I am sorry to bug you though

Comment: You are using the name `transaction` twice. You bound it once in the second half of your `MATCH` statement and then again in your first `CREATE` statement. You can't have two nodes called `transaction`. You need to pick a different name for one of them.

Comment: can we chat some where . skype,fb anything ?

Comment: Sorry... I am not available to chat right now. Are you still having issues with your CSV load?